# hacer un cronometro en cuenta regresiva delphi

Tags: delphi

saludos, me he estado preguntando como poner una cuenta regresiva de un minuto osea un cronometro por decirlo así para después unirlo a un semáforo que hice con formas y temporizadores  para cuando inicie por ejemplo esta en rojo dure 59 segundos después pase a amarillo y así sucesivamente. Hasta ahora solo he podido poner que los semáforostexto en negrita cambien entre si. aqui mi progreso:

```
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
Timer1.Interval := 2500;
timer2.Interval := 3000;
timer3.Interval := 1500;
shape3.Brush.Color := clGreen;
shape2.Brush.Color := clOlive;
shape1.Brush.Color := clRed;
timer1.Enabled := false;
timer2.Enabled := true;
timer3.Enabled := false;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer2Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin

shape2.Brush.Color := clYellow;
shape1.brush.Color := clMaroon;
timer2.Enabled := false;
Timer3.Enabled :=  true;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer3Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
shape3.Brush.Color := clLime;
shape2.Brush.Color := clOlive;
shape1.Brush.Color := clMaroon;
timer1.Enabled := true;
```

Comment: ¿Qué precisión esperas que tenga el semáforo?

Answer (score 1):

Dado que has mencionado un semáforo y un cronómetro de cuenta regresiva, he realizado un pequeño ejemplo funcional, si bien valiendome del uso de TTimer, no de la misma manera que tu lo planteas en la pregunta.

Primero, veamos el semáforo funcionando:

[image: Semáforo funcionando (GIF)]

Lo he hecho utilizando Firemonkey, pero la idea básica es la misma si utilizas VCL.

Tengo un formulario con 3 `TCircle`, que serán las *luces* del semáforo. Un [`TStopWatch`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.Diagnostics.TStopwatch) de la unidad `Diagnostics`, que es el que me sirve para llevar la cuenta del tiempo transcurrido, y un `TTimer` establecido a un intervalo de 50ms.

El evento OnTimer es este:

```
procedure TForm1.tTiempoTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if FStopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds > FSegundosAEsperar * 1000 then
    CambiarDeColor;
  ActualizarEtiqueta;
end;
```

Como puedes ver, este manejador de evento, tira de estos dos métodos:

```
procedure TForm1.CambiarDeColor;
begin
  case FColorEncendido of
    Verde: EstablecerColor(Amarillo, SegundosAmarillo);
    Amarillo: EstablecerColor(Rojo, SegundosRojo);
    Rojo: EstablecerColor(Verde, SegundosVerde);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.ActualizarEtiqueta;
var
  FaltaMSec: Int64;
  Min, Sec: Word;
begin
  FaltaMSec := FSegundosAEsperar * 1000 - FStopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + 950;
  Sec := (FaltaMSec div 1000) mod 60;
  Min := (FaltaMSec div 1000) div 60;
  lblTiempo.Text := Format('%.2d:%.2d', [Min, Sec]);
end;
```

El método `CambiarDeColor` tiene la lógica básica del funcionamiento del semáforo, y el método `ActualizarEtiqueta` la del funcionamiento del cronómetro de cuenta regresiva. Para el funcionamiento de este último, almaceno en un miembro de la clase el tiempo de espera de la luz en curso, y la primera línea del método obtiene la diferencia entre el tiempo que hay que esperar y el tiempo transcurrido, más un poco menos de un segundo, ya que de otra forma el cronometro mostraría el texto '00:00' durante todo un segundo antes del cambio de color, y no es el comportamiento que espera ver el usuario.

Finalmente, el método `EstablecerColor` se encarga de ajustar los colores del semáforo cada vez que ocurre un cambio de color, y de reiniciar el `FStopWatch` para que comience de nuevo la cuenta del tiempo transcurrido desde 0.

```
procedure TForm1.EstablecerColor(AColor: TColorSemaforo; ASegundos: Integer);
var
  cRojo: TAlphaColor;
  cAmarillo: TAlphaColor;
  cVerde: TAlphaColor;
  cEtiqueta: TAlphaColor;
begin
  FColorEncendido := AColor;
  cRojo := TAlphaColorRec.Indianred;
  cAmarillo := TAlphaColorRec.Palegoldenrod;
  cVerde := TAlphaColorRec.Darkseagreen;
  cEtiqueta := TAlphaColorRec.Silver;
  case AColor of
    Verde:
      begin
        cVerde := TAlphaColorRec.Lime;
        cEtiqueta := cVerde;
      end;
    Amarillo:
      begin
        cAmarillo := TAlphaColorRec.Yellow;
        cEtiqueta := cAmarillo;
      end;
    Rojo:
      begin
        cRojo := TAlphaColorRec.Red;
        cEtiqueta := cRojo;
      end;
  end;
  LuzRoja.Fill.Color := cRojo;
  LuzAmarilla.Fill.Color := cAmarillo;
  LuzVerde.Fill.Color := cVerde;
  lblTiempo.TextSettings.FontColor := cEtiqueta;
  FStopWatch.Reset;
  FStopWatch.Start;
  FSegundosAEsperar := ASegundos;
end;
```

Finalmente, la declaración de la clase:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    LuzRoja: TCircle;
    LuzAmarilla: TCircle;
    LuzVerde: TCircle;
    lblTiempo: TLabel;
    tTiempo: TTimer;
    procedure tTiempoTimer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    const
      SegundosVerde = 7;
      SegundosAmarillo = 3;
      SegundosRojo = 10;
    type
      TColorSemaforo = (Verde, Amarillo, Rojo);
    var
      FColorEncendido: TColorSemaforo;
      FStopWatch: TStopWatch;
      FSegundosAEsperar: Integer;
    procedure EstablecerColor(AColor: TColorSemaforo; ASegundos: Integer);
    procedure CambiarDeColor;
    procedure ActualizarEtiqueta;
  public
  end;
```

El resultado es el que ves en la imagen de arriba, que la he realizado con una captura de pantalla luego de ejecutar este proyecto.

Comment: Muchas Gracias por enseñarme como hacerlo se te agradece :)

Comment: pero hay cosas que no entiendo osea soy muy nuevo en la programación por ejemplo el ´stopwatch´ del que hablas no me aparece por ningun lado y tampoco se donde va y no sé tampoco de  la unidad de 'Diagnostics' y en una parte vi este codigo ' lblTiempo.Text := Format('%.2d:%.2d', [Min, Sec]);' mas o menos me podrías ayudar a entender lo de %2d y esas cosas? y lo de 'Mod' y 'div tambien'

Comment: El StopWatch es una clase de la RTL, de la que me valgo para llevar la cuenta del tiempo. Añade *System.Diagnostics* a la clausula uses de tu sección *interface*, para tenerla ya disponible. *Format* es una rutina de uso bastante común, te dejo un link a la documentación: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.SysUtils.Format

Comment: div y mod son operadores para obtener el cociente y el residuo de una división entre números enteros. Su uso es bastante típico, lo que ves me permite convertir una cantidad X de segundos en Y minutos y Z segundos, para mostrarlo de la forma mm:ss. Si tienes preguntas adicionales, no dejes de considerar publicarlas como preguntas en el sitio, pues la sección de comentarios a veces no da para tanto. ;)

Comment: Muchas Gracias por responder y seguiré investigando para aprender :)

Comment: En este caso, mi respuesta tiene prácticamente todo el código para armar el ejemplo. ¿Has podido compilarlo?